# C#: Make a field only modifiable using the class that contains it

Tags: c#, class, encapsulation

I'm sure this has been asked before I just don't know the correct way to word it so I can't find what I am looking for.

I have a class with a field which I want to be able to see from the outside, just not be able to modify it directly..

```
public class myclass
{
    public int value;
    public void add1()
    {
        value = value + 1;
    }
}
```

So I would really like to only have the 'value' field *modifiable* from the method `add1()` but I still want to be able to see the value of 'value'.

EDIT: I was thinking only modifiable via the class `myclass`, but I typed otherwise. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider the following options to encapsulate a field (i.e. provide an "interface" for the private field value):

1. Provide the public method (accessor):

   ```
   // ...
   private value;
   // ...
   public void Add()
   {
       ++value;
   }

   public int GetValue()
   {
      return value; 
   }
   ```
2. Provide the public property (only accessor):

   ```
   // ...
   private value;
   // ...

   public void Add()
   {
       ++value;
   }

   public int Value
   {
      get { return value; }
   }
   ```
3. Provide the auto-implemented property (public accessor, private mutator):

   ```
   // ...
   // The field itself is not needed: private value;
   // ...

   public void Add()
   {
       ++Value;
   }

   public int Value { get; private set; }
   ```

It is worth noting that some IDEs or IDE–plugins provide the appropriate refactoring called "Encapsulate Field".

Answer (score 5):

```
public int value { get; private set; }
```

You cannot make it modifiable *only* by the method `add1`, but you can make it only modifiable by `myclass`.

See this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75e8y5dd.aspx

Comment: So this would be restricting the accessor? I laughed when I read that the set accessor was inaccessible.

Comment: @UpTide This is called auto-property. and `private set` means only modify it inside class.

Comment: Please note that if the property is something like a list, a private setter will prevent one from changing the list reference but will not prevent manipulations within the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use public property without setter to just see the `value` from outside. make the `value` private so its only visible inside the calss.

```
public class myclass
{
    private int value;
    public void add1()
    {
        value = value + 1;
    }
    public int Value
    {
       get
       {
           return value; 
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to using this method over Rob's method?

Comment: no. we just gave solution at sametime. but i recommend you use auto-property as Rob's suggested. with auto-property you define all of this in one line @UpTide

Comment: The only advantage is that you can modify value or do some extra tasks in getter of this property. however its not possible for auto-property @UpTide

Comment: @UpTide There is an upside *if* you have custom logic in `get` or `set`. If it's simply returning the value, it will compile to (essentially) the same code.

Comment: I see, so if for some reason I want to; I could add 10 to the value before getting it.

Comment: @UpTide That's correct.. the `get { }` is just a short form of writing: `public int GetValue() { return value; }` (and in fact it does compile to the method `get_Value()`) - so you can implement any logic you wish. Simply writing `get;` does not allow you to implement custom logic, but is simpler to write.